# Getting text name of current project CRS in QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling, expression, qgis-print-layouts

I'm want to display the current project projection in a QGIS layout.

Right now I can get QGIS to display the current EPSG number like below:

[image: Current Solution]

But what I want to do is get QGIS layout to print the ESPG name as well like below with an expression:

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you will need a custom function to do this, the following seems to work though I haven't tested it extensively.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def getCrsDescription(feature, parent):
    """
    Returns the description text of the project CRS
    <h2>Example usage:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>getCrsDescription() -> WGS 84</li>
      <li>getCrsDescription() -> OSGB 1936 / British National Grid</li>
    </ul>
    """
    return iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs().description()
```

Comment: Script works well - it's a shame we need a custom function rather than in inbuilt one. I'll see if I can raise it as a suggestion in GitHub

Comment: It would seem like it should be available as a variable

Comment: Didn't see the issue filed, so took the liberty myself: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35113

Comment: Fixed!
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/a10bb387a767c21b27d345138227286ac2bd7ce2

Answer (score 3):

This behavior will be improved in an upcoming release of QGIS due to the below fix by Nyall Dawson and Alex Royas:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/a10bb387a767c21b27d345138227286ac2bd7ce2

**New expression variables:**

project_units

- Unit of the project's CRS

project_crs_description

- Name of the coordinate reference system of the project

project_crs_acronym

- Acronym of the coordinate reference system of the project

project_crs_ellipsoid

- Acronym of the ellipsoid of the coordinate reference system of the project

project_crs_proj4

- Proj4 definition of the coordinate reference system of the project

project_crs_wkt

- WKT definition of the coordinate reference system of the project